# Why does the following code autoboxes to wrong types and compiles?

Tags: java, generics, casting, autoboxing

```java
class Test {
    public static <T> boolean test(T a, T b) {
        return a.equals(b);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 0;
        long j = 0;
        if (!test(i, j)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("i is not equal to j");
        }
    }
}
```

In the code snippet above I am expecting one of the following two things to happen:

1. There will be a compiler error, because `i` is autoboxed to `Integer` and `j` is autoboxed to `Long` and the declaration of the method `test` requires that both of its arguments are of the same type.
2. Both `i` and `j` to be autoboxed to Long and the code to compile and run showing that `i` and `j` are equal.

But what happens actually is `i` is autoboxed to `Integer` and `j` is autoboxed to `Long` and the code compiles without error. Doesn't this contradict with the declaration of `test`? What is the reason to allow such code?

Comment: I assumed that the compiler will "see" that it should find a common class to cast both i and j to and the answer would be Long because that way there is no losing of precision. But as it was explained the compiler sees that it wants i to be autoboxed to Integer and j to be autoboxed to Long and _then_ tries to satisfy T and succeeds by choosing for example Number. (edited as I further understood what actually happened)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `i` is boxed to an `Integer` and `j` is boxed to a `Long`, it's still legal to call the method `test` with its generic type assumed to be [`java.lang.Number`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html), which is a supertype of both `Integer` and `Long`.

In fact, you can call your `test` method with *any* two objects, because `T` can be taken as the base type `Object`. The generics on the method do not restrict its arguments at all.

Comment: Indeed, the signature may as well just be `boolean test(Object a, Object b)`